# Find my look a like in a stack of photos

Tags: comparison, face-recognition

I am looking for my own look a like in my school. I have 1500 photos that were made on photo day, including my own.

Now I want some way to find the face that looks the most like me. How would I go about this?

Comment: upload them all to facebook and let Zuckerberg sort it out.

Comment: Nah. Facebook would find a 100% match which is not what i want X-D

Comment: If it's not 100% then how is it a look a like? If there are differences, what are the differences? How would software detect this?

Comment: Upload them to facebook and then within a week's time ask the NSA for the results!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a face recognition command line tool?](http://superuser.com/questions/420885/is-there-a-face-recognition-command-line-tool)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using Picasa Facial Recognition?

Picasa contains a facial recognition feature similar to Picasa Web Albums, but it will catalog the collection of photos on your hard drive.

Perhaps it being hit or miss sometimes, you may be able to find that doppelganger you're searching for.

[Lifehacker has an interesting article on the function.](http://lifehacker.com/5365267/picasa-35-organizes-your-photos-with-facial-recognition)